# Connect Talend to Salesforce using OAuth JWT Flow

Tags: integration, connected-apps, talend

I followed the steps exactly mentioned here https://help.talend.com/reader/4cgA8~D~pdi5biHRfSvg_Q/ZoXS~zBdrcuQAx427Yv6Gw for connecting Talend to salesforce.

I have done the configuration in Talend and added the test(sandbox) URL in the advanced setting. I am facing an error while trying to establish the Oauth connection (JWT) between Talend ETL tool and salesforce: `{'error':'invalid_grant','error_description':'invalid assertion'}`
Here is the screenshot of the configuration and error message:
[image]

Please help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 4):

Currently, Talend doesn't support JWT Flow for the sandboxes(test.salesforce.com). It only supports prod environments. I have personally faced this issue, where we have used username and password to connect to the test environments and JWT for production.